# Angular: Share events in an Angular Service and using the same component twice on the page

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

My custom table consists of several components. Each of these components emit their events using a common service `TableEvent`.
All these events are subscribed in a class `TableTemplate` that manages the communication between the various components of the my custom table.

Everything works fine if the page has only one table, with more tables the events are performed on all the tables and are not on the one that generated the event. How I can fix this issue?

```
@Injectable()
export class TableEvent {
    private sortChangeSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    public sortChange = this.sortChangeSubject.asObservable();

    public sortChangeEmit($events) {
        this.sortChangeSubject.next($events);
    }
}

export abstract class TableTemplate implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    protected constructor(public tableName: string, public options:TableConfig = {}) {
        this.tableEvent = AppInjector.get(TableEvent);
        this.subscription.add(this.sortChangeEvent());
    }

    protected sortChangeEvent() {
        return this.tableEvent.sortChange.subscribe($event => {               
            this.load($event);
        });
    }

    protected abstract setColumnDef(): ColumnDef[];

    protected abstract getDataSource(optionFilters?, optionsSort?): Observable<T>;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-clients',
    templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./clients.component.scss']
})
export class ClientsComponent extends TableTemplate {
    protected setColumnDef(): ColumnDef[] {
        return [...];
    }

    protected getDataSource(optionFilters?, optionsSort?): Observable<Object> {
        return ...
    }
}

<!-- clients.component.html -->
<app-table
    [sortName]="'id'"
    ...
</app-table>
```

I edited to add more code. `TableTemplate` is a class not a component. The component that implement my custom table must inherit from `TableTemplate`.

Adding

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [TableEvent]
})
```

to `ClientsComponet` or `TableComponent` I get the message `no providers for TableEvent`

I'm using Angular 7.1

Comment: You have an `injectable` which is provided in the `root`. This means the service is a singleton so the same instance of the service is used for all of the components which inject it. You likely need to use `providers: []` (with `multi: true`) at a `@Component` level, so that you get a new instance of the service for each component ([docs](https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components))

Comment: I get "NullInjectorError: No provider for TableEvent"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing the `TableEvent` service at the [table component level](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-services-in-modules-vs-components) will ensure that each table has its own service instance:

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [TableEvent]
})
export class TableComponent extends TableTemplate {
  ...
}
```

Make sure that you remove the root provider in the service definition:

```
@Injectable()
export class TableEvent {
  ...
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyn7os) for a demo.

Comment: In this way, I get "NullInjectorError: No provider for TableEvent" ( i edited my message with more code)

Comment: In the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyn7os?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.component.ts), the component passes the service to the base class constructor.

Comment: Thanks to answer. Is not possible to avoid setTableEvent in each component?

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz (after posting the previous comment) to pass the service in the base class constructor. You could also set a `protected tableEvent: TableEvent` property. In any case, the component must tell the base class that the service is available.

Answer (score -1):

You must set an instance id for each component and send soource and destination of event to the service.and each component check destination id.